# For private list <webelement> correct definition for following-sibling

Tags: jquery, css, xpath, intellij-idea

I am creating an Xpath for a private list for webelement using following-sibling. I tried to create a list with the products from the homepage: `http://automationpractice.com/index.php`

With the following Xpath it doesn't follow the products list:

```
xpath="//ul[contains (@class, 'product_list grid row homefeatured')]/following-sibling:: li"
```

How can I create the correct Xpath for the list webelement?

The script:

```
<ul id="home-page-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs clearfix">
<div class="tab-content">
<!-- Products list -->
<ul id="homefeatured" class="product_list grid row homefeatured tab-pane active">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 first-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line last-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 first-in-line last-line first-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-line last-item-of-tablet-line last-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-line first-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line last-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
</ul>
<!-- Products list -->
```

[image: Screeenshot]

Comment: Did any answers mentioned below helped your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think for the given url, the class attribute which contains `product_list grid row homefeatured` does not have [following-siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) with `li`. The following sibling from that point would be the next `ul`.

Maybe you are looking for:

`//ul[contains(@class, 'product_list grid row homefeatured')]/li`

To get all the list items from both `ul`'s, you could use for example:

`//ul[contains(@class, 'product_list grid row')]/li`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are using `<ul id="home-page-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs clearfix">` to get to the `li` elements shown in your image. To do that, your xpath should look like

`.//ul[@id='home-page-tabs' and @class='nav nav-tabs clearfix']/following-sibling::div[@class='tab-content']/ul[@id='homefeatured' and @class='product_list grid row homefeatured tab-pane active']/li`.

Probably what is not working in your case is that in your xpath, your `ul` with `"id="home-page-tabs"` and your `li` with `"@id='homefeatured"` are not in the same hierarchy i.e. they have different parents. Hence you cannot use `following-sibling` to get `li`. What you can do, is go to `div` which is the `following-sibling` of your `ul` and then get to your `li` which is the child of that `div`.

Hope this explains and helps.